# SQL. Поставить признак, если значения строк совпадают

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, некоторые ID в табличке совпадают, но при этом значения других столбцов разные, можно ли технически как-то через IF в новом столбце проставить признак "1", если совпадение есть и "0", если его нет? Всё это в запросе.

Comment: Запросто. EXISTS.

Comment: А если я селектом хочу все строки со всеми столбцами достать, при этом проставив признак, у меня это получится?

Comment: Ну я ж сказал - EXISTS. Естественно, в подзапросе отсеять текущую запись. Ну или можно оконной функцией - результат тот же... а при наличии правильного индекса может и побыстрее выйдет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и с подзапросом, как предлагали в комментарии, но это будет приемлемо работать только на небольшом количестве строк или если по ID есть индекс.
Например так:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table as T2 
    WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
  ) > 1
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isDuplicated, T1.*
FROM your_table as T1
```

Можно ещё без повторного обращения к таблице с помощью оконных функций:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY ID) > 1 
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isDuplicated, your_table.*
FROM your_table
```

На всякий случай проверьте оба варианта. Какой быстрее зависит от многих факторов.

Возможно вам достаточно/удобней будет получить список проблемных ID, для этого можно выполнить такой простой запрос:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) as duplicatedCount
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Вау, спасибо! А можно, например, вывести уникальные значения по ID (все столбцы, но при этом, чтобы в уникальном значении дата шла самая новая, так как повторяющиеся значения отличаются только по датам)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Id, CAST(COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) - 1 AS BIT) AS HasDuplicate
FROM TableName
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: - 1 AS BIT   -   оно конечно работает, но попахивает обфускацией))

Comment: @pegoopik возможно, зато решение короткое, что вот меньше уже сложно представить, поэтому можно догадаться + имя столбца говорящее, как и тип данных